# Actionbarsherlock use activities or fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, android-support-library

I've been working on a school project in a course for Mobile prototype for a couple of weeks when our mentor said we should change our way of navigate in the app.

Before the app started with a simple menu where the user could chose which feature to open, which could be different activities, listactivities, mapactivities, activities with custom views, ect.

We then found the ActionBarSherlock library which could help us make a nice tab bar. But should we then change our activities to be fragments (supportfragments runs 2.3.3) or can we keep it as (normal) activities? if so how to best show this under each tab.

Actionbarsherlock have been implemented successfully in our apps start activity and now we "only" need to make the navigation to the existing the activities or change them to fragments.

Do tell if this isn't clear what have described or you need any further information.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish you can only use Activities with ActionBarSherlock

It all depends on what your want to achieve and the use of fragment might help you making a cleaner app.

Actionbarsherlock sample: 
1° [tab bar with fragment & viewpager](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/actionbarsherlock-samples/fragments/src/com/actionbarsherlock/sample/fragments/FragmentTabsPager.java)

2° [tab bar with fragment](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/actionbarsherlock-samples/fragments/src/com/actionbarsherlock/sample/fragments/FragmentTabs.java)

Comment: I want to create a tab bar with actionbarsherlock and think i would have to use fragments or am I wrong? I thought that would be the easiest with the use of fragment transaction, but please correct me if im wrong

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer, I have managed to create it using Actionbar. Are there any benefits using tab host instead of action bar?